# Create an immutable base with generic methods

Tags: java, android, inheritance, immutability

I have a base class as such:

```
public abstract class BasePiece extends Serialisable {
    public final Position[] shape;
    public final Position position;

    public abstract Position[] getInitialShape();

    public BasePiece() {
        position = new Position(0, 0);
        shape = getInitialShape();
    }
    public BasePiece(Position pos, Position[] initialShape) {
        position = pos;
        shape = initialShape;
    }

    public BasePiece Moved(Position offset) {
        return BasePiece(position.add(offset), shape);
    }

    public BasePiece Rotated() {
        return BasePiece(position, shape.Rotated());
    }
}
```

However I would like Moved and Rotated to return instances of the class which inherits this class. I'm rather new to Java, and having some experience of C# I tried to do the following:

```
public <T extends BasePiece> T Moved(Position offset) {
    return T(position.add(offset), shape);
}

public <T extends BasePiece> T Rotated() {
    return T(position, shape.Rotated());
}
```

Is there any way of doing this? My initial attempt at solving this is to make shape and position no longer final, and to make Moved and Rotated Move and Rotate methods which mutate this state. I really want to make the objects immutable as it will make a lot of the rests of my app much more manageable

Comment: Compilation note:  Serializable is an Interface.  Your abstract base class needs to implement it, not extend it, so you will get a compilation error on that line.  I suspect you already knew that and it was just a typo.

Comment: Also, you're calling a method `Rotated()` off of an array, but an array does not have any such method.  The compiler will give you a `symbol not found` error.

Comment: Gah sorry I tried to simplify my example a little too much, I actually have a class defined here which does have a rotated method, you're right about implements/extends too

Answer (score 1):

I think this have very little to do with generics. You can leave the declaration of your method as:

```
public BasePiece Moved(Position offset) {
        return BasePiece(position.add(offset), shape);
}
```

and in a class that extends it:

```
class ExtendPiece extends BasePiece {

    @Override
    public BasePiece Moved(Position offset) {
            return ExtendPiece(position.add(offset), shape);
    }

}
```

as by `ExtendPiece` can be down casted to `BasePiece`.

But then of course you will have to cast it yourself:

```
ExtendPiece e = (ExtendPiece) obj.Moved(..);
```

**EDIT:**

Just a quick workaround would be to use so-called double dispatch:

make every subclass implement method `newInstance()` which will be abstract in Base Class. In ExtendedPiece:

```
public BaseClass newInstance(Position pos, Position[] initialShape){
    return new ExtendedPiece(pos, initialShape);
}
```

and the code of your abstract method as:

```
public BasePiece Moved(Position offset) {
     return this.newInstance(position.add(offset), shape);
}
```

Comment: But this then means I have to override for every subclass, I have 7 of them, and only want my abstract method to be overridden

Comment: Ohhh, sorry I absolutely did not see the `T(position.add(offset), shape);` inside the method

Comment: +1 for the edited version. Unfortunately verbose, but saves the cost of doing reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to define your generic method only once in the base class, and have them work automatically in your subclasses.

Yes, this can be done in Java.  It's a bit more verbose than it is in C#, but here's how you would do it.

First, you would have to add this to your base-class declaration:

```
public abstract class BasePiece<T extends BasePiece<T>> implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Then, in your method, do this (it involves reflection, you'll have to import java.lang.reflect.Constructor):

```
public T Moved(Position offset) {
        //Use reflection to invoke the constructor
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Constructor<T> constructor = (Constructor<T>) this.getClass().getConstructor(Position.class, Position[].class);
        T newInstanceOfSpecificType = null;
        try {
            // Cast result to T, which will be the subclass
            newInstanceOfSpecificType = (T) constructor.newInstance(position.add(offset), shape);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof NoSuchMethodException) {
                throw new RuntimeException("You forgot to declare the appropriate constructor in " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "!\n");
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newInstanceOfSpecificType;
    }
```

The one catch:  You'll have to make sure to define the constructor with the signature (Position, Position[]) in all your subclasses, and you'll have to declare your subclasses specifically, like so:

```
public class ExtendedPiece extends BasePiece<ExtendedPiece> {

    public ExtendedPiece(Posistion position, Position[] shape) {
        return super(position, shape);
    }

}
```